# How to get multipart request data in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, multipart

I am trying send HttpPost request from Android to C# (.net 3.5) aspx server. I am using Apache multipart entity builder builds entity at Android side:

```
entityBuilder.addTextBody("username", username);
entityBuilder.addTextBody("password", password);
entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file);
```

And try to get data at C# server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;  // only username and password keys received.

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
         string [] tmp = Request.Form.GetValues (keys[i]);
    }
}
```

I can get TextBody part keys and values in the Request (username and password). But no BinaryBody key or data received. I do not know why?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Should I expected to answer my own question in stackoverflow? My reputation lost 2 points after answered my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
HttpFileCollection MyFiles = Request.Files;
// ...
for (int l = 0; l < MyFiles.Count; l++)
{
    if (MyFiles.GetKey(l) == "file")
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = MyFiles.Get("file");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the *Form* variables, where your code creates a blob that's send inside the HTTP request's body. The body isn't a form variable, it's simply the content inside an HTTP request that comes after the headers.

HttpRequest understands the contents of an HTTP request and exposes the various parts through its properties, eg [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx), [Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx), [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx), [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx).

If your code sends the binary data as a File, check the [Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Otherwise, you can read the contents of the body using the [InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Assuming the data can be found in Files, the documentation of [HttpPostedFile.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) describes how to read the file:

```
var files=Request.Files;
var aFile=files[0];

var length = aFile.ContentLength;
byte[] input = new byte[length];

aFile.InputStream.Read(input,0,length);
```

`InputStream` is just a stream so you can copy its contents in a buffer, write it out to disk etc

Comment: Is `var files Request.Files;` a typo? I changed it to `var files = Request.Files;` and test it in my code, but when I try to access the page from browser, I just got `Argument Out Of Range Exception` at `aFile.InputStream.Read(input,0,length);` line. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of length? How many files are there? What are their names and lengths? Which one did you try to read? Can you post a sample of the HTTP Request? Just the fact that you can get the first file with `files[0]` means the request contains *at least* one file.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Finally I solved it. The solution is simple, I updated the original question with the solution. Thanks again!